# Get nested key inside #each loop in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

Imagine my data looks like this:

```
{
  data: [
    { col1: 'Value1', col2: 'Value2', col3: 'Value3', col4: 'Value4' },
    { col1: 'String1', col2: 'String2', col3: 'Stringe3', col4: 'String4' }
    ...
  ],
  query: ['col1', 'col3']
}
```

I want then to show with handlebars the data whose keys matches one of the items in `query` (here: I only want to show `col1` and `col3`of each row of the data). How would I do that?

Here is what I tried:

```
{{#each data}}
  <tr>
    {{#each ../query}}
      <td>{{../this[this]}}</td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

But unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{{#each data}}
    <tr>
    {{#each ../query}}
        <td>{{lookup ../this this}}</td>
    {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```